# find the node with minimal value in binary tree with foldr

Tags: haskell

Someone can help me to define a function minTree, that find the node with minimum value in a binary tree using foldr.
I start something, but I don't know how to use foldr within my code:

```
data Tree a 
    = Leaf
    | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
    deriving (Show, Eq)

  minTree :: (Ord a) => Tree a -> Maybe a
  minTree Leaf = Nothing
  minTree (Node Leaf a _) = Just a
  minTree (Node left a _) = minTree left
  minTree = foldr...
```

I am stuck on how define foldr to return the minimum Node

Comment: it looks better now or I need to modify those lines?

Comment: The type signature of [`foldr`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=foldr&scope=set%3Astackage) is: `Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b` so you would need first to convince the GHC compiler that your tree structure is an instance of the Foldable class. Did you try your luck with the -XDeriveFoldable extension ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is as follows:

```hs
data Tree a 
    = Leaf
    | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
    deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Foldable Tree where
  foldr f ini Leaf = ini
  foldr f ini (Node left x right) = f x $ foldr f (foldr f ini right) left

minTree :: (Ord a) => Tree a -> Maybe a
minTree tree = foldr minMaybe Nothing tree

minMaybe :: (Ord a) => a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
minMaybe x Nothing = Just x
minMaybe x (Just y) = Just (min x y)
```

The `Foldable` instance implementation for `Tree` is post-order traversal (right-left-root), which is the main part of the code.  `minMaybe` can probably be avoided using built-in functions, but I kept it expressive so the main part remains clear.

As @ammalloy has pointed out, we can get rid of `minMaybe` and make use of `coerce`, `foldMap`, and the `Min` Semigroup. Honestly, I don't know how `coerce` works but `foldMap` applies a function to the data wrapped in a data type with a `Foldable` instance and aggregates the results using their `Monoidal` operation `<>`, which is why `Min` is used here.

```hs
data Tree a 
    = Leaf
    | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
    deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Foldable Tree where
  foldr f ini Leaf = ini
  foldr f ini (Node left x right) = f x $ foldr f (foldr f ini right) left

minTree :: (Ord a) => Tree a -> Maybe a
minTree = coerce . foldMap (Just . Min)
```

Comment: `minTree = coerce . foldMap (Just . Min)`

Comment: Thank you @amalloy I've added that to the answer. This is somewhat beyond my knowledge. Please check and correct if you see fit. Thanks.

Comment: @amalloy It bugs me that using that needs to wrap every element in a `Just`, which has a cost, even though it's known for sure whether the final answer will be a `Just` or `Nothing` as soon as the root element is examined.

Comment: Yeah, it's not really ideal. If Prelude's `minimum` were safe, we could just use that. As it is, I can't think of any cheap one-liners. If we were willing to use two lines, we'd just check for Leaf and otherwise call `minimum`.

Comment: You don't need `coerce`. Just `getMin` or whatever it's called.